# flatMap with a map in scala

Tags: scala

Why doesn't this work:

```
val m = Map( 1-> 2, 2-> 4, 3 ->6)
def h(k: Int, v: Int) = if (v > 2) Some(k->v) else None
m.flatMap { case(k,v) => h(k,v) }
m.flatMap { (k,v) => h(k,v) }
```

The one with the `case` statement gives me:

```
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 4, 3 -> 6)
```

but the other one fails and says `MIssing Type parameter v`, and `expected: Int, actual:(Int, Int)`

Answer (score 4):

The `case` keyword signifies pattern matching, so the `Tuple2` (a `Map`is an `Iterable` of`Tuple2` elements) that you are flatMapping "over" gets decomposed into k and v. (The fact that `flatMap` works when the `h` function is producing an `Option` rather than a `Map` or `Iterable` is the Scala collections library being perhaps overly permissive.)

Without the `case` keyword, you are providing a function that requires two arguments, but `flatMap` needs a function that accepts a single argument (a `Tuple2`). So the second version does not typecheck.

Comment: It's worth noting that Dotty [will perform automatic tupling](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/auto-parameter-tupling.html), so both snippets would be valid

Answer (score 0):

For second one you can do this, if you don't want to use `case`.

`m.flatMap { x => h(x._1, x._2) } // x is (key,value) pair here(each element in map), hence accessing the key , value as _1,_2  respectively`